# Add expires header to django with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I use django_compress to compress my static files. All static files are collected under /static/ url using collectstatic command. Now I want to add expires headers to this files. There is no problem to do this with apache, but when I add to my nginx.conf:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/proj/static;
    expires 7d;
}
```

and restart the server then static files are not served. What should I change?

The location is under server context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refs http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root, a request such as http://yourserver/static/foo will be directed to /home/user/proj/static/static/foo . Is the static/static right structure on you server?
Also run nginx -t to ensure there is no error in configuration, before reload nginx.